# Java Array Addition

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a Java code that counts votes of certain paintings. I wanted to collect what the user vote and add it to a running total so that it prints the total votes after each user has voted.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void Gallery()
    {

       // Declare variables
       //
    String total = "-33";
        String[] paintings = {"Mona Lisa","Water Lilies","The Scream","A Young Rembrandt"};
    int[] scores = {0,0,0,0};
        String searchKey; //the thing looked for
  // 


       //now can get an answer quickly without calculating just looking it up
    for (int y=0; y<paintings.length; y++)
    {
        System.out.println("Vote "+ (y+1) + " for " + paintings[y]);
    }


       for (int i=0; i<paintings.length; i++)

            {
            String vote = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which painting would you like to vote for?");
            if (paintings[i].equals(vote))
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You voted for " + vote); 
            paintings[i] + 1 = scores[i];
            for(int z=0; z<paintings.length; z++)
            System.out.println(scores[z] + " " + paintings[z]);
        }

        if(total.equals(vote))
        {


        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry");
        }

       }


    }
```

I want it so that say the user votes 'Mona Lisa' this would add '1' to the first integer in 'int [] scores'? How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using some kind of `Map<String,Integer>` ?

Answer (score 2):

This line looks a bit weird to me:
    paintings[i] + 1 = scores[i];

I think what you want to put here instead is this:
    scores[i]++;

To address your question about the scores array being reset, modify like this:

```
static String[] paintings = {"Mona Lisa"...};
static int[] scores = {0,0,0,0};
```

By statically declaring these variables, your variables will be initialized only once, which means they will retain their state on subsequent calls to your function.  Declaring the paintings array static is really just an optimization, but declaring the scores array as static solves your real problem.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but if i enter Mona Lisa twice it doesn't say 2 :/

Comment: It is because you are creating scores array every time you call your method. So when you call your method again and again it declares your scores array with default values.

Comment: How would i avoid this? The program works perfectly for the first loop but doesnt work properly for the second loop if the same painting is entered again. @Emusc